# Is there way to sync iPhone/YouTube/Facebook?

Tags: facebook, youtube, iphone

I currently upload videos directly from iPhone to you tube... Is there a way to push the videos from YouTube to my facebook status when they are uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the upload sharing activity works the same whether it is from a mobile device or a computer.

Access your [Activity Sharing](http://www.youtube.com/account#sharing/activity) in your Account.

Under this message

> Your activity feed is the actions that you take on YouTube like favoriting, rating, or uploading a video.

Select Yes, allow a selected set of my activities to be viewable.

Then include the actions you want to share in your feed under

> **What activities do I share?**

In this case,

> ✓ Upload a video

Finally make sure to connect your Facebook Account under

> **Where do I share my activities?**

I know that sometimes the activity fails to update the Facebook status, happens to me when I like a video or favorite a video. But most of the times it works.